# How to solve the issue? Access to XMLHttpRequest'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'

Tags: reactjs

How to resolve this issue? 'https://gentle-woodland-78175.herokuapp.com/chack-isAdmin?email=undefined' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Comment: can you provide a description of the stack you're using? this error shows that your server is setting a policy which prohibits the loading of items (images, text) from a different source than the server itself. To change the behaviour you need to set the server so that it allows requests from the client to other urls, but this step depends on the server you're running (node, express, django, flask, rails...)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define CORS policy on back end (On the code or on the application server ).
Or check it by using chrome CORS extension.

For example on node js envrionmnet.

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const app = express();
app.use(cors())
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.json({
        message: 'Hello World'
    });
})
```